# Как сделать чтобы ввод текста был однострочным?

Tags: android

У меня есть EditText и в нём следующие настройки:

```xml
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_text_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:hint="@string/search_placeholder"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/fdGeneralTextColor"
            android:textColorHint="@color/fdGrayTextColor"
           android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"/>
```

Если писать текст и нажать ентер, то можно писать с новой строки. Как запретить вторую строку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Атрибут textMultiLine разрешает ввод многострочного текста, его надо убрать.

```
android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences"/>
```

Comment: Точно! Видать скопировал из другого шаблона и забыл убрать)) Спасибо)